# Getting Reference from Android MediaPlayer Buttons

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

Okay guys, I have a  MediaController SetAnchorViewed to a VideoView.
I intend to override what happens when user clicks pause button.

The problem is that I have no reference to the pause button. (No resource ID)

How can I set an onclicklistener to the pause button of the mediaplayer?